# Is it possible for string data bindings to render its HTML contents?

Tags: polymer

I have this template:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[faq]]">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="question">[[item.question]]</div>
    <div class="answer">[[item.answer]]</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And I have an `item.answer` string that contains an HTML anchor to link to another page. This `<a></a>` just renders as text on the page. I tried a simple `<br>`, and this renders as text too.

Is it possible to for string data bindings to render its contents as HTML? If not, how can I still link to something else?

Answer (score 2):

There are custom elements that support rendering the HTML from a string property, including [`<juicy-html>`](https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-html).

```
<template is="juicy-html" content$="[[item.answer]]"></template>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      html: {
        type: String,
        value: '<a href="#/baz">baz</a><br><a href="#/qux">qux</a>'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/juicy-html+juicy+:v1.0.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="juicy-html/juicy-html.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <template is="juicy-html" content$="[[html]]"></template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VPbbbN?editors=1010)

There is also a hacky workaround you could use to bind to an element's `innerHTML`:

```
<div inner-h-t-m-l="[[item.answer]]"></div>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      html: {
        type: String,
        value: '<a href="#/foo">foo</a><br><a href="#/bar">bar</a>'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div inner-h-t-m-l="[[html]]"></div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/XpRRRE?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

couldn't dom-repeat be implemented in such a way it could be applied to any tag, e.g.:

```
<li is="dom-repeat" items="...">
```

This would not only fix this issue but also made the final DOM simpler, i.e. there would be no extra  nodes in the DOM.

I understand that ability to apply dom-repeat to any tag may not be a good idea performance-wise but maybe this could be resolved by additional declaration? Sth like:

```
<template>
  <ol>
    <li is="dom-repeat" items="...">
  </ol>
  <div class="footer" is="dom-if" if="{{showFooter}}">(...)</div>
</template>

<script>
  Polymer({
      is: "my-element",

      extendedElements: ['li', '.footer', 'another css selector'],

      (...)
<script>
```

Then Polymer would need to check the is attribute of elements matching one of extendedElements selector only.

I guess this could be applied to dom-if and possibly other extensions too.

Comment: Huh? In what way is this an answer to my question?

Comment: The dom-repeat element is a custom HTMLTemplateElement type extension that automatically stamps and binds one instance of template content to each object in a user-provided array. dom-repeat accepts an items property, and one instance of the template is stamped for each item into the DOM at the location of the dom-repeat element. The item property will be set on each instance's binding scope, thus templates should bind to sub-properties of item.